# How to find frequency of the resulting wave where amplitude aren't same?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, superposition

> In the superposition of two coherent waves $($at $x=0$$)$ given by $$y_1=4\sin(300\pi t)$$ and $$y_2=2\sin(308\pi t).$$
> Find the frequency of the resulting wave and the frequency at which the amplitude of the resulting wave varies.

---

Now this question is quite simple, if the amplitudes of both waves are same. We just add those two trigonometric functions. But what to do when the amplitudes aren't same. My teacher said that the information given is insufficient to tell the things asked. Is it so$?$ To be honest, I don't know that much math that I can add expressions like $$A\sin C+B\sin D$$

Is there any other method of finding the frequency$?$ Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $$y_2+y_1=3(\sin308\pi t+\sin300\pi t)-(\sin308\pi t-\sin300\pi t)=6\sin304\pi t\cos4\pi  t-2\cos304\pi t\sin4\pi t$$, which, while it is horrible to find the envelope, is actually pretty clearly a wave that is quickly oscillating with $304\pi t$ and slowly oscillating with $4\pi t$; It is incredibly likely that the question is really asking for this.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent the answer to the first question was 152Hz and to the second was 2Hz

Comment: Which you can read off from my answer.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent yea... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, only a sum of equal amplitudes waves can be easily written as a single trig function of varying amplitude. It is non-trivial (maybe possible, but not in my knowledge) to write your sum as a single product of trig functions. However, it is still a wave of some given amplitude and some given frequency.

Let's call your sum of waves $x(t)$. To find the frequency, you simply need to find the period which is the minimal $T$ such that $x(t+T)=x(t)$. This is manageable.
$$ 4 \sin(300\pi t + 300 \pi T) + 2 \sin(308 \pi t + 308 \pi T) = 4 \sin(300\pi t) + 2 \sin(308 \pi t) $$
so that $300 \pi T = 2 \pi k_1$ and $308 \pi T = 2 \pi k_2 $ where $k_1$, $k_2$ are integers implying
$$ T = \frac{k_1}{150} = \frac{k_2}{154} \implies 154 k_1 = 150 k_2 $$
we need to find the smallest $k_1$,$k_2$ satisfying this relation. This corresponds to finding the least common multiple of $150$ and $154$, which is $154 * 75 = 150*77$, so $k_1=75$, $k_2=77$ and $T= \frac{k_1}{150} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Concerning the amplitude, I would search for the maximum and the minimum of $x(t)$ (setting the derivative to 0), whose difference would give twice the amplitude.

With this method you can find both the amplitude and the frequency of this superposition, even without knowing an explicit trig form of the sum, which may not even exist.

Comment: I think your attempted answer is very far away from what is actually being asked.